# change parameter in a flutter package method

Tags: json, flutter, dart, file, flutter-web

I added a package in my flutter web project ([flutter_azure_b2c](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_azure_b2c)). The package is working fine but I have a problem that I dont want to pass a json file to the package method instead I want to pass the json object directly.
Can I change this by forking the github library or do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Don't fork it. Forking will create a maintenance disaster for your project.

Comment: better to create new addtional function with `extension method` . Extension methods add functionality to existing libraries. https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods